# Rails 3. How to setup two instances of the same model in a belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

If I have a table called `enrollments` and this is my current basic enrollment setup:

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base      
  belongs_to :father
  belongs_to :mother
  belongs_to :child
end

class Father < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :children
  validates :first_name, :presence => true
  validates :last_name, :presence => true
end
```

Now I want to add a `guardian_1_id` and a `guardian_2_id` to the`enrollments` table. How would I set that up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be best off using a polymorphic association, e.g.

```
class Enrollment 
  belongs_to :enrollable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Father
 has_many :enrollments, :as => enrollable
end
```

This shoudl give you some flexibility in terms of whether there are 1, 2, or more guardians per situation. Also, you could add validation that caps it at two.